# IDE for HP Calculator Programming?

Tags: ide, calculator

Typing in programs longer than 50 characters got old really fast on my HP49g+.

What IDEs are designed for programming HP calculators? Are there any plugins to Visual Studio, Eclipse, xCode, etc. for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a C cross compiler called [hpgcc](http://hpgcc.org/).

Comment: Wow, that's cool! Now I don't have to stumble through those stupid HP languages!

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm using [HPUserEdit4](http://www.hpcalc.org/details.php?id=4746) (with the English translation). Pros are syntax highlighting, a built-in emulator, a list of common symbols to insert.

It's decent, but not great by any means and debugging is nowhere near what it's like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

- [A collection of programming utilities (even IDEs) for hp49g+/50g](http://www.hpcalc.org/hp49/pc/programming/) (there is even a search on the whole site)
  Anyway I suggest:
- debug4x
- UEdit
- HPuser edit